# Language recommendation for XML checking

Tags: xml, validation

I want to build an XML document validator. A program that goes through an XML document and looks for attribute repetition and consistency based on defined patterns (not that the XML is consistent with the standard, but the attributes comply with specific rules).

I have experience working with:

- Java
- Perl
- Groovy
- C#
- C

What language/library/extension would you recommend for such task ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: How will it be hosted and on what platform?

Comment: It's a client app. Can be run on Windows or Linux.

Comment: Have you ever heard of XML Schema?

Comment: If XML Schema can't express your patterns, I would look into using Schematron http://www.schematron.com/ before building your own custom validator.

Answer (score 0):

I would use libxml2 or one of it's implementations in any of the languages you prefer. How one validates the specific document depends on the XML dialect it's using. There are currently three common validating mechanisms: DTD, RelaxNG and XML-Schema and every self-respecting dialect produces at least one of these with it's dialect specification.

The following a C version for validating a MathML document using RelaXNG:

```
static const xmlChar
mml_rng_uri[] = "http://www.w3.org/Math/RelaxNG/mathml3/mathml3.rng";

/**
 * @brief Validate the MathML document located at the given URI.
 */
/*
 * -- Implementation notes --
 *
 * The goal is xmlRelaxGNValidateDoc.
 * For that we need a xmlDocPtr for the document and xmlRelaxNGValidCtxtPtr
 * for the RelaxNG schema.
 * Given a uri we can use xmlCtxtReadFile for the document.
 * We will also need a validation schema, which is always the result of a
 * RelaxNG parse operation.
 * The parse operation requires a parser context obtained from either
 * xmlRelaxNGNewParserCtxt, which takes an URI or xmlRelaxNGNewMemParserCtxt
 * which takes a pointer and size.
 *
 * -- Short hand --
 * xmlRelaxNGValidateDoc()
 *   |
 *   |- xmlDocPtr = xmlCtxtReadFile()
 *   |  |
 *   |  |- xmlParserCtxtPtr = xmlNewParserCtxt()
 *   |
 *   |- xmlRelaxNGValidCtxtPtr = xmlRelaxNGNewValidCtxt()
 *   |  |
 *   |  |- xmlRelaxNGPtr = xmlRelaxNGParse()
 *   |  |  |
 *   |  |  |- xmlRelaxNGParserCtxtPtr = xmlRelaxNGNewParserCtxt()
 *   |  |  |- xmlRelaxNGParserCtxtPtr = xmlRelaxNGNewMemParserCtxt()
 */
int MML_validate(const char *uri)
{
    xmlDocPtr doc;
    xmlParserCtxtPtr docparser;
    xmlRelaxNGValidCtxtPtr validator;
    xmlRelaxNGPtr schema;
    xmlRelaxNGParserCtxtPtr rngparser;
    int retval;

    /* RelaxNG schema setup */
    rngparser = xmlRelaxNGNewParserCtxt(mml_rng_uri);

    if( (schema = xmlRelaxNGParse(rngparser)) == NULL )
        errx(1, "Failed to parse MathML RelaxNG schema");
    if( (validator = xmlRelaxNGNewValidCtxt(schema)) == NULL )
        errx(1, "Failed to create a RelaxNG validator");

    /* MathML document setup */
    if( (docparser = xmlNewParserCtxt()) == NULL )
        errx(1, "Failed to create a document parser");
    if( (doc = xmlCtxtReadFile(docparser, uri, NULL, XML_PARSE_XINCLUDE)) ==
            NULL )
        errx(1, "Failed to parse document at %s", uri);

    /* Validation */
    retval = xmlRelaxNGValidateDoc(validator, doc);

    /* Clean up */
    xmlRelaxNGFreeValidCtxt(validator);
    xmlRelaxNGFreeParserCtxt(rngparser);
    xmlRelaxNGFree(schema);

    return(retval);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's far too short a requirements statement to make a definitive statement, but it sounds like a Schematron problem to me.